# When Walking The Rules Collection How Do I Determine If A Rule Has An Error And What The Error Is?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

Outlook Version 2211 (Build 15831.20208 Click-to-Run)
Access Version 2211 (Build 15831.20208 Click-to-Run)

```
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 
'   Get the Outlook objects we need 
Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
Set olStore = olFolder.Store 
Set olRules = olStore.GetRules 
lRecordNumberEnd = olRules.Count 
        For Each olRule In olRules
```

***** Is there a way to determine if a rule has been classified as in error from the olRule object and possibly what the error is?

If I am processing a rule that moves a message to a specific folder, I will get an error when I try to reference the folder name:

```
  Case olRuleActionMoveToFolder '   Rule action is to move the message to the specified folder." 
       Set olMoveOrCopyRuleAction = olAction 
       On Error Resume Next 
           rs.Fields("Information").Value = "     " & "     " & olMoveOrCopyRuleAction.Folder 
           If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
               If Err.Number = 91 Then 
                    rs.Fields("Information").Value = "     " & "     " & "***** Folder not defined *****" 
                Else 
                     rs.Fields("Information").Value = "     " & "     " & Err.Description 
                End If 
                rs.Fields("Status").Value = " **Error**" 
            End If 
       On Error GoTo 0
```

Now if you are in Outlook and click on Rule/Manage Rules and Alerts, Outlook will display a single popup:

> One or more rules contain errors.  Delete or modify these rules.

So, Outlook has a simple way to determine that at least one enabled rule is in contains an error.  If the rule that has an error is disabled, Outlook still highlights it in the list of rules.

So, my question is:
How do I identify that a rule has an error and what the error is without having to process the rule and throw an error?

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268992/handling-errors-in-outlook-rule

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to do that, but you can do a sanity check on at least the rules that point to a folder, such as copy or move action rule - check `Rule.Actions.MoveToFolder` / `CopyToFolder` actions are enabled, try to access `MoveOrCopyRuleAction.Folder` property and see if it raises an error.

Comment: The code I posted does that.

Comment: So do you see an error logged in that case?

Comment: Yes.   See:  If Err.Number = 91 Then 
                    rs.Fields("Information").Value = "     " & "     " & "***** Folder not defined *****"

Comment: So you get an error (as expected) when you access the folder. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: The object model for a rule Exchange Outlook has an IsInError property that can be checked to see if the rule has an error without executing it.  Is that type of property hiden somewhere in the non-Exchange version of Outlook an if so where is it?  I have a system with over 1800 rules.  When you go into Rules & Alerts Outlook knows immediately if at least one rule has an error.  When you walk the rules & alerts there is a flag that says if a rule or alert is in error without executing it.  Where is that information kept?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Rules.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.rules.save) method do diagnose if anything is wrong with a rules. Saving rules that are incompatible or have improperly defined actions or conditions (such as an empty string for `TextRuleCondition.Text` or wrong folder used) will return an error.

`Rules` are not fully exposed in the object model. You can use VBA to create the rules, but not repair them. For example, see [Create a Rule to Move Specific Emails to a Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/rules/create-a-rule-to-move-specific-e-mails-to-a-folder).

Comment: I think you missed: So, my question is:
How do I identify that a rule has an error and what the error is without having to process the rule and throw an error?

Comment: I understood it correctly. There is  no such mechanisms in the Outlook object model. The best what you could do is to try calling the `Save` method to diagnose if anything is wrong with a rules like it was stated in my post.